# Is there any benefit in not enum cards c#

Tags: c#, enums, playing-cards

I'm going to create a card class in C# for a poker game. All needed actions with cards are going to be implemented in other classes like deck or hand or combination. 
What type of fields should I use for rank and suit, **string** or **enum** or **int**? 
Is there any advantage to not using enums?

Comment: Integers are more resource intensive than entire string objects? Where do you get your information?

Comment: What makes you think an `enum` is resource-intensive? It's not.

Comment: This question is pretty good, apart from the "As far as I understand..." bit, which just reflects a misunderstanding. I'm going to edit that bit out if you don't mind, and try to provide an answer.

Comment: Using strings is a dreadful idea. Strings are for humans, not computers. Simple integers make it easy to compare cards, index into lookup tables, and perform well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with `enum` for both rank and suit.

Why?

- Readability of code. While creating new instance of class you can create it like this:

  `var card = new Card{ Rank = Rank.King, Suit = Suit.Hearts}`
- Less error-prone - if suit was an `int`, you could put any number between `int.MaxValue` and `int.MinValue`, but only some of values are going to have a meaning. Just try to find the little bug if you wrote 11 instead of 10 somewhere in code, and all of sudden your deck has five kings.
- Do not be afraid of memory usage - enum is just a nice-looking int, as mentioned in answer by Anders Forsgren. And you can make it a `byte`, if you need only 8 values, which will take a memory of, well, around one byte. Which considering you are using C# is negligible. Enum can be any of `byte`, `sbyte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, or `ulong`.

So, keep it `enum` and have better-looking, less error-prone, faster code.

Comment: Actually you can set the value of an enum to anything as well, which means point two only matters if the enum is set manually and not by value ex. `{ Rank = (Rank)int.MaxValue, Suit = (Suit)int.MaxValue }` would be valid.

Comment: That's true, but it is still easier to keep it safe with enums than ints. You can try to cast any value(or - anything really, including objects) to enum, but if it is not a valid value an exception is raised.

Comment: I'd say it's more convenient than safe

Answer (score 2):

Enum is the obvious choice for something that is a *value type* with a finite number of options. Card ranks and suits matches these criteria very well.

Enums can be considered syntactic sugar over integers, so performance wise it's the same as using a simple integer. There is nothing gained by *not* using an enum here.

Answer (score 2):

I would say enums are optimal. Integers will be similar performance wise, but using an enum improves readability and also makes it harder to assign an illegal value.